# Defined Contribution Plan - Are IRA Contributions Included in the Yearly Elective Deferral Limits?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, simple-ira

I am under the assumption that the elective deferral limit for defined contribution plans (including Simple IRAs and 401ks) is $18,000.  IRAs have a separate $5,500 limit.  Does the $18,000 limit include IRAs or is the IRA contribution limit in addition to the standard defined contribution plans' limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 401(k) contribution limits only apply to 401(k)s, not IRAs. The limits are separate. The IRA may or may not be deductible, based on income thresholds.